# React cli SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, консоль

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
'use strict';
const React = require('react');
const {render, Text} = require('ink');

const App = () => {
    return  (
        <Text>Test text</Text>
    )
}

render(<App />);
```

Код выше, при попытке запустить через node выдается ошибка такая. При этом если где-то оно так, а где-то работает, импорты одинаковые. В самой документации есть примеры такого вида скрипта, но не работает почему-то.

Вот ошибка

```
E:\Desktop\test\cli.js:8
        <Text>Test text</Text>
        ^

    SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'
        at Object.compileFunction (node:vm:352:18)
        at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1031:15)
        at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1065:27)
        at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
        at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
        at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
        at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
        at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47
```

Comment: Nodejs не умеет выполнять jsx. Да и никто не умеет. Обязательно  должна быть компиляция (явная или неявная) в нормальный JavaScript

Comment: Но почему выполняет, если я импортирую сюда другой файл js? Вот пример от разработчика https://github.com/vadimdemedes/ink

Comment: И где там запуск jsx файла? В сборке я вижу вызов `tsc`, т.е. компиляцию.

Comment: Ну и вот в примерах используется [`import-jsx`](https://github.com/vadimdemedes/ink/blob/master/examples/jest/index.js#L4) который (видимо) под капотом компилирует jsx в нормальный js.